# Evaluating $\int_0^\pi x\frac{\sin{\frac{x}{2}} - \cos{\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> How am I supposed to solve the following definite integral?
> $$
> \mathcal{I} = \int_0^\pi x \cdot \frac{\sin{\frac{x}{2}} - \cos{\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}} dx
> $$

---

This definite integral is solved if the **minus sign is replaced by a plus sign**, and it yields $\pi^2$.

$$
\mathcal{I} = \int_0^\pi x \cdot \frac{\sin{\frac{x}{2}} + \cos{\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}} dx \text{ 
— (I)} \\
\implies \mathcal{I} = \int_0^\pi (\pi - x) \cdot \frac{\cos{\frac{x}{2} + \sin{\frac{x}{2}}}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}} dx \text{ 
— (II)}
$$

On (I) + (II), we have,

$$
\mathcal{I} = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin{\frac{x}{2}} + \cos{\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}} dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}+\cos{\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{1 - (\sin{\frac{x}{2}-\cos{\frac{x}{2}}})^2}} dx
$$

On substitution,
$$
\sin{\frac{x}{2}} - \cos{\frac{x}{2}} = u \implies \left(\sin{\frac{x}{2}} + \cos{\frac{x} {2}}\right) dx = 2 \cdot du
$$

The upper and lower limits changes to 1 and -1. Now, we have

$$
\mathcal{I} = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{2 \cdot du}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} du = \pi \cdot \left[\arcsin{u}\right]_{-1}^1 = \pi^2
$$

---

### But...

1. **The sign was not supposed to be changed.** We get $(2x - \pi)$ instead of $\pi$ in the nominator when adding both integrals. It complicates the problem.
2. Using **integral-calculator.com** or a **scientific calculator** is helpless.
3. The answer to the original problem should be $2\pi \cdot \ln{2}$ (approx 4.35.)

Comment: @HelpMeToUnderstandContours By using the definite integral rule: $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(a + b - x) dx$

Comment: I didn't notice the $x$ before $\frac{\cos{\frac{x}{2} + \sin{\frac{x}{2}}}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}$. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution using real analysis. First, denote the two integrals as

\begin{align*}
J & \equiv\int\limits_0^{\pi}\frac {x\left(\sin\frac x2\color{red}-\cos\frac x2\right)}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,\mathrm dx\\K & \equiv\int\limits_0^{\pi}\frac {x\left(\sin\frac x2\color{red}+\cos\frac x2\right)}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,\mathrm dx
\end{align*}

And from your post, recall that $K=\pi^2$. Adding the two integrals together removes the $\cos\frac x2$ factor inside the integrand, leaving only

\begin{align*}
J+K & =2\int\limits_0^{\pi}\frac {x\sin\frac x2}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,\mathrm dx\\ & =\sqrt 2\int\limits_0^{\pi}x\sqrt{\tan\frac x2}\,\mathrm dx\\ & =4\sqrt{2}\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac {\sqrt t}{1+t^2}\arctan t\,\mathrm dt
\end{align*}

Where a double angle identity was utilized in the second equation and the half-angle tangent substitution in the third equation. The last integral has been evaluated here before using [Complex Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007015/is-it-possible-to-evaluate-the-integral-i-int-0-infty-frac-sqrtx-arctanx?noredirect=1), [Feynman's Trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480888/feynman%C2%B4s-trick-to-solve-int-0-infty-frac-arctanx-sqrtx1x2-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1), etc. Here is an alternative approach using double integrals. First, enforce the substitution $x=\sqrt t$ so that the integral becomes

$$\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac {\sqrt t}{1+t^2}\arctan t\,\mathrm dt=2\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac {x^2}{1+x^4}\arctan x^2\,\mathrm dx$$

Next, use the identity

$$\arctan x^2=\int\limits_0^1\frac {x^2}{1+x^4 y^2}\,\mathrm dy$$

Swapping the order of integration and using partial fraction decomposition, then we get

\begin{align*}
2\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\,\int\limits_0^1\frac {x^4}{(1+x^4)(1+x^4y^2)}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx & =2\int\limits_0^1\frac 1{y^2-1}\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac 1{1+x^4}-\frac 1{1+x^4y^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\\ & =\frac {\pi}{\sqrt 2}\int\limits_0^1\frac 1{y^2-1}\left(1-\frac 1{\sqrt y}\right)\,\mathrm dy\\ & =\frac {\pi^2}{4\sqrt 2}+\frac {\pi\log 4}{4\sqrt 2}
\end{align*}

To recap, we have the equation

$$J+\pi^2=4\sqrt{2}\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac {\sqrt t}{1+t^2}\arctan t\,\mathrm dt=\pi^2+\pi\log 4$$

Subtracting a $\pi^2$ from both sides, then

$$\int\limits_0^{\pi}\frac {x\left(\sin\frac x2-\cos\frac x2\right)}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,\mathrm dx\color{blue}{=\pi\log 4}$$

Comment: It is the best answer I could understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

$$I=\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin{\frac{x}{2}} - \cos{\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}x dx=2\sqrt2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\Big(\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}\Big)xdx=2\sqrt2(I_1-I_2)$$
Both terms converge, so we can evaluate them separately.

Making the substitution $x=\arctan t$ and $\arctan t=\int_0^1\frac{t}{1+t^2x^2}dx$
$$I_1=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt t}{1+t^2}\arctan tdt=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{t\sqrt t}{(1+t^2)\big(t^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\big)}dt$$
To evaluate the first integral we go in the complex plane and integrate along a keyhole contour. We have four simple poles ($\,\pm i; \,\,\pm\frac{i}{x}\,$).

The straightforward evaluation gives
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{t\sqrt t}{(1+t^2)\big(t^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\big)}dt=\frac{2\pi i}{2}\underset{z=\pm i; z=\pm\frac{i}{x}}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{z\sqrt z}{(1+z^2)\big(z^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\big)}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}\frac{1-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x(1-x^2)}x^2$$
Therefore,
$$I_1=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt x(1+\sqrt x)(1+x)}=\sqrt2\pi\int_0^1\frac{dt}{(1+t)(1+t^2)}$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}\int_0^1\Big(\frac{1}{1+t}+\frac{1-t}{1+t^2}\Big)dt$$
Integration is straightforward and gives
$$I_1=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}+\ln2\Big)$$
In the similar way we evaluate $I_2$ (using $\sqrt{\cot x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan x}}$ and making the same substitution $x=\arctan t\,$)
$$I_2=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt t}{(1+t^2)\big(t^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\big)}dt=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+\sqrt x)(1+x)}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}-\ln2\Big)$$
$$\boxed{\,\,I=2\sqrt2(I_1-I_2)=2\pi\ln2\,\,}$$
And, as a bonus,
$$J=2\sqrt2(I_1+I_2)=\pi^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your effort. However, my level of understanding is not that much at the moment. Despite this, it motivated me to learn Mathematics.

Comment: I have a slight objection to your evaluation of the residue. You are trying to evaluate a residue of a function involving sqrt(z), but this is not a holomorphic function - it requires a branch cut etc. Is it valid to ignore this when computing a residue, eg. via taylor approximation around x when x!=0 (so any given branch of sqrt(z) is analytic in a neighborhood around x!=0)?

Comment: @Faraz Masroor Thank you for your comment. In fact, the keyhole contour includes the cut (from $0$ to $\infty$ along the axis $X$) - to make the integrand a single-valued function. We also have to make sure that the integrals around $z=0$ and along a big circle do not contribute. I skipped all these steps, because the given integrand is an appropriate function for the keyhole integration. The detailed examples of keyhole integration may be found, for example, here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233396/how-can-i-use-residue-theory-to-verify-this-integral-formula

Answer (score 7):

$$I=\int_0^\pi x \frac{\sin{\frac{x}{2}} - \cos{\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}} dx\overset{IBP}=4\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{1+\sin x})dx$$

$$\overset{\large x\to \frac{\pi}{2}-2x}=8\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\ln\left(\sqrt{\cos(2x)}+\sqrt 2 \cos x\right)dx\overset{\cos x\to x}=8\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}^1\frac{\operatorname{arccosh}(\sqrt 2x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

---

$$\require{cancel}
\mathcal J(a)=\int_\frac{1}{a}^1\frac{\operatorname{arccosh}(ax)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\Rightarrow \mathcal J'(a)=\frac{1}{a^2}\frac{\cancelto{0}{\operatorname{arccosh}\left(a\frac{1}{a}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{a^2}}}+\int_\frac{1}{a}^1\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-a^2x^2}\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

$$\overset{1-x^2\to x^2}=\frac1a\int_0^{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{a^2}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{a^2}-x^2}}dx=\frac1a\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{a^2}}}\right)\bigg|_0^\sqrt{1-\frac1{a^2}}=\frac{\pi}{2a}$$

---

$$I=8\left(\mathcal J(\sqrt 2)-\mathcal J(1)\right)=4\pi\int_1^\sqrt 2\frac{1}{a}da=2\pi \ln 2$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. It helped me understand the $\arccosh(x)$ function. I'm looking forward to learning more.

Answer (score 4):

Evaluate \begin{align}
I=& \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x(\sin x- \cos x)}{\sqrt{\sin{2x}}} dx
=\int_0^{\pi/2} x\ d\bigg(- \tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2\tan x}}{1+\tan x}\bigg)\\
\overset{ibp}=&\int_0^{\pi/2} \tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2\tan x}}{1+\tan x}
\overset{t= \tan x}{dx}
=\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+t^2}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2t}}{1+t^2}dt=J(1)
\end{align}
where $J(a)= \int_0^\infty \frac1{1+t^2}\tanh^{-1}\frac{a\sqrt{2t}}{1+t}dt$
\begin{align}
J’(a)=&\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{2t}(t+1)}{(1+t^2)(t^2+2(1-a^2)t+1)}\overset{t\to t^2}{dt}\\
=& \ \frac{\sqrt2}{1-a^2}
\int_0^\infty \frac{t^2+1}{t^4+1}- \frac{t^2+1}{t^4+2(1-a^2)t^2+1}\ dt\\
= &\ \frac\pi{1-a^2}\bigg(1-\frac1{\sqrt{2-a^2}}\bigg)
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi x\frac{\sin{\frac{x}{2}} - \cos{\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}} dx=&\ 4I=4J(1)=4\int_0^1 J’(a)da\\
=&\int_0^1 \frac{4\pi}{1-a^2}\bigg(1-\frac1{\sqrt{2-a^2}}\bigg)da=2\pi\ln 2
\end{align}